# Safe use of Pymongo's find_one

Tags: pymongo

Whats the behavior of Pymongo `find_one`? I would expect such a function to return a None or throw an exception when it does not find the required document. But it behaves like:

```
>>> q = db.find_one({'node_type': {'$regex':'impossible-condition'}})
>>> q
>>>
>>> q==1
False
>>> w==1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'w' is not defined
```

Does it return anything? And how to safely determine if the query did not match a value?

Comment: did you try: `>>> q is None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `find_one` is the collection level operation, you need to actually provide collection that you are querying against. Taking your example, we will look at the users collection:

```
q = db.users.find_one({'node_type': {'$regex':'impossible-condition'}})
```

After that the following applies: `find_one` returns single document, or None if no matching document is found.

See:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one